# Not enough space when there is, WIndows 10 installation?

Tags: windows-10

Alright, when I go to install Windows 10 from a flash drive, it says "Not enough free space" when there is, and I have no clue as to why. Would someone be ale to help me?

Comment: So how much space is available? Did you select the correct destination drive?

Comment: I'm not really sure which drive is considered correct, but I tried them all with 3 different partitions and I thought I put the amount of free space in my question, but it's C: 100, X: 40, E: 160. This is all gig wise

Comment: Format the C drive and install it, you can do.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that it was my system reserve partition. When I ran the Windows 10 setup from within Windows 7 the message with regard to system reserve which was too small.

So I increased it from 100 MB to 4 GB.